# homebrew how to use versions tap

Tags: version, homebrew

Following some online directions to install older versions of formulae, get this:

```
% brew tap homebrew/versions

Error: homebrew/versions was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.
```

What does this mean and where have they migrated to/what to do now as its alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages/formulae in tap `homebrew/versions` are merged into `homebrew-core`. If you wanna find an old version of a package. Just search it in the homebrew-core tap,

```
❯ brew search go
==> Formulae
algol68g                                  go@1.14                                   googler                                   mongo-orchestration
anycable-go                               go@1.9  
...
go@1.10                                   google-benchmark                          libgosu                                   wireguard-go
go@1.11                                   google-java-format                        lunchy-go                                 write-good
go@1.12                                   google-sparsehash                         mongo-c-driver
go@1.13
```

Basically all old package are migrated as `package@X.Y` in homebrew-core.

BTW, homebrew-core is the default tap included after homebrew installation.

Comment: OK looks like there is no longer a "versions" cask it is all inline as you mention.  So if it's not in main you have to use some of the other funky tricks floating around. Except for casks which still have `homebrew/cask-versions` LOL